# How to map React Icons in react

Tags: reactjs

I have the icon imports above

```
import { MdSettings } from "react-icons/md";
import { RiAccountPinCircleFill } from "react-icons/ri";
import { BsSunFill } from "react-icons/bs";
```

then here is the array containing the imports

```
const Icons = ["MdSettings", "RiAccountPinCircleFill", "BsSunFill"];
```

I want to map it here

```
<div className="topbar-links inline-flex">
        <ul>*this is where I want it rendered*</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if your variable is not a component, you should avoid to use PascalCase for the name. So you can rename `Icons` as `icons`.

Then, you should store the elements imported directly in the array and not just their names as string, or you will not be able to use the components:

```
const icons = [MdSettings, RiAccountPinCircleFill, BsSunFill];
```

Finally, for the loop you can do like this:

```
<div className="topbar-links inline-flex">
   <ul>
      {icons.map((Icon, i) => (
         <li key={i}>
            <Icon />
         </li>
      ))}
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the icons are react components you can store the icons as

```
const Icons = [<MdSettings/>, <RiAccountPinCircleFill/>, <BsSunFill/>]
```

then you can map them as

```
<div className="topbar-links inline-flex">
        <ul>{Icons.map((icon, index) => <li key={index}>{icon}</li>}</ul>
</div>
```